# httpClient.get not calling the server after upgrade to Angular 8

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

After upgrading my app from Angular 7 to Angular 8, the `httpClient.get` in my `APP_INITIALIZER` will not call the server, causing the promise not to resolve and the basically not to load.

`app.module` providers section:

```
  providers: [
    ConfigService,
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: loadConfig,
        deps: [ConfigService],
        multi: true,
    },
  ]
```

`APP_INITIALIZER`:

```
export function loadConfig(configService: ConfigService) {
  return () => configService.load(`/assets/config/config.json`);
}
```

`ConfigService.load`:

```
    public load(configUrl: string): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log('Getting config');
            this.httpClient
                .get<any>(configUrl)
                .subscribe(
                    (response) => {
                        console.log('response', response);
                        this.configurationLoaded.next(true);
                        resolve();
                    },
                    (err) => reject(err),
                );
        });
    }
```

When I try the same in a minimal reproduction, it works like it's supposed to. I tried on different machines (macos & Windows). Rolling back the upgrade also makes the app work again. Upgrading again leads to the same, non-functioning app.

The only real difference between my app and a minimal repro is the fact that I didn't set up `ngrx/platform` on the minimal repro.

I understand that there will most likely not be any clear cut solution to this problem but any help in debugging it would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: replacing the `httpClient.get` by an `XMLHttpRequest` does seem to work. I got it from https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/931#issuecomment-468825180. So it definitely has something to do with the upgrade from ngrx 7 to ngrx 8.

Comment: but you can see in the network tab `configUrl` is called?

Comment: Maybe this will help? > If you use the legacy HttpModule and the Http service, switch to HttpClientModule and the HttpClient service. HttpClient simplifies the default ergonomics (you don't need to map to JSON anymore) and now supports typed return values and interceptors. https://update.angular.io/#7.0:8.0

Comment: change resolve(); to resolve(true); Also a stackblitz producing a minimal reproduction of the error would help us help you.

Comment: `configUrl` is not called. Obviously I'm not using the old HttpModule, this was removed in Angular 8 and has been deprecated since Angular 4 (?). `resolve()` is actually never called since the `httpClient.get` never calls the server, hence the observable does not emit.

Comment: Your problem is somewhere else as this is working with Angular 8 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7hdiw1

Comment: If you consider loading the config in the store I would attempt to dispatch an action and load the config from an effect on APP_INITIALIZER something like is shown in this post https://dev.to/jonrimmer/where-to-initiate-data-load-in-ngrx-358l if possible or like https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/931#issuecomment-469046579 suggests

Comment: If you don't actually load the `config.json` from a remote server but from your local assets folder you can simply import the json file in typescript. See: https://medium.com/@baerree/angular-7-import-json-14f8bba534af